# Does casting of a primitive type increase/decrease memory usage?

Tags: c++

I was trying to conserve as much memory as possible in my program. I needed to have decimal precision when it came to outputting some data. My thought was to create variables as `int` and then cast as a `double` when I needed the decimal percision.

Here is an example

```
int x, y, z;
cin >> x >> y >> z;

cout << (double)x/2 << endl << (double)y/2 << endl << (double)z/2 << endl;
```

Does this make the variables take up as much space as a `double` in memory?

There is also the similar case but backwards,

```
double x, y, z;
cin >> x >> y >> z;

cout << (int)x/2 << endl << (int)y/2 << endl << (int)z/2 << endl;
```

Would the variables then take up less space?

My overall question is **does casting of a primitive type increase/decrease memory usage?**

Comment: The variables *themselves* will not change by casting. However the *temporary* values created and passed to the `operator<<` functions needs space, of course, but as said they are only *temporary*. And possibly stored in registers instead of in memory and in that case use no memory at all. Perhaps if you could elaborate on the *actual* problem you have, *why* you want to know this, then we could give some better answers?

Comment: @Gary Slightly more stack space is needed for the operator function calls, so yes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My problem was if by creating an int and casting as a double when precision was needed saved memory. Then turned into a broader question to understand the memory usage of casting. Your comment clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your question is quite *architecture-dependent*.

In *general*, no `stack` space should be reserved for *those* casting operations.

Just to give you an idea, the assembly output (on an x86-64 compiled with 32 bit with `gcc` w/o any optimisations) is the following:

```
fildl   -12(%ebp)
fldl    .LC0
fdivrp  %st, %st(1)
subl    $4, %esp
leal    -8(%esp), %esp
fstpl   (%esp)
pushl   std::cout
call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(double)
```

The function invoked at the end is, as expected, `std::operator<<(double)`.

As you can see, the casting operation is consumed in the first three instructions. The `double` value is saved in a temporary register `st`.

Although the double is a temporary register, the situation is a little bit different with the call to the `std::cout<<` operator. That's because the argument is a `double` (and not an integer). For that reason the allocated stack for the `std::operator<<(double)` function is slightly bigger than a `std::operator<<(int)` (in that architecture a double takes 8 bytes, and integer 4 bytes).

In conclusion, with the casting operation:

- Obviously, the code size will increase because the *casting* operation will introduce additional machine instruction in order to perform the casting.
- The reserved stack in the function calling is slightly bigger because the `operator<<` reserve a double.

In general all those "*side-effects*" does not really matter on general architectures. You *maybe* should care about that (especially regarding floating point operation) on embedded architectures.

Answer (score 1):

There are two usage of memory:

- program memory: memory usage for storing the code itself
- data memory (stack/heap): used for data

Your casts will probably increase the length of the program by a few instructions (few bytes), which is usually not any concern.

On the other hand, a cast will not increase data memory (the cast is temporal and disappear as soon as it is consumed)

Finally, the size in memory between using int or double:

- int is usually take 32bit on now-a-day computers
- double is usually 64bit

So saving huge amount of data as int instead of double could make sense.